# Handle escaping closure in non escaping function

Tags: swift, memory-management, closures

In the following code I get the error.

> Passing non escaping parameter 'completion' to function expecting an
> @escaping closure.

```
protocol DetailViewControllerDelegate: AnyObject {
    func detailViewController(_ controller: DetailViewController, doneButtonPressed button: UIBarButtonItem)
}

final class DetailViewControllerDelegateHandler: DetailViewControllerDelegate {
    
    typealias DismissComplete = () -> Void
    typealias Action = (DismissComplete) -> Void
    
    var dissmissScene: Action?
    
    private let model = Model()

    func detailViewController(_ controller: DetailViewController, doneButtonPressed button: UIBarButtonItem) {
        
        dissmissScene? { [unowned self] in
            let value = controller.value
            self.model.update(with: value)
        }
    }
}

final class HomeViewController: UIViewController {

    private let delegateHandler = DetailViewControllerDelegateHandler()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        delegateHandler.dissmissScene = { completion in
            // error here
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: completion)
        }
    }

    func buttonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let controller = DetailViewController.instantiateFromStoryboard()
        controller.delegate = delegateHandler
        present(controller, sender: self)
    }
}
```

What can I do about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `completion` closure is not escaping. Because `dismissScene` is a function that accepts a non-escaping closure. Notice that the type of `dismissScene` is `Action`, which is `(DismissComplete) -> Void`, which in turn is `(() -> Void) -> Void`. The inner `() -> Void` is not marked `@escaping`.

You just have to mark it as so:

```
typealias Action = (@escaping DismissComplete) -> Void
```

Comment: Ah, I had no idea you could mark it as escaping like that. Thank you.